# What is the difference between "android_get_control_socket" and "socket_local_client"?

Tags: java, android, ipc

In android i have seen two socket related APIs. What is the difference between **android_get_control_socket** and **socket_local_client**

Does they solve the same purpose?
Which one is more suitable?

-Giri

Comment: Where have you seen that? cant find something with that name in the Android API. Anyway you only need the Socket and ServerSocket classes that comes with java and you can use like in any other java app.

Comment: this is part of RilSocket.cpp

Comment: Is that part of the Android NDK API?